# Automatic edge creation in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to use OrientDB to map the relationship between servers that are managed by multiple different systems (with some overlap).  Suppose that each server from each system was a vertex, is there a way to create an edge automatically between two servers that have the same property (e.g. IP address)

Suppose this is my starting data (in CSV format)

```
System,  Name,        IP
---------------------------------
Alpha,   compute-1,   192.168.0.1
Alpha,   compute-2,   192.168.0.2
Beta,    storage-1,   192.168.0.1
Beta,    storage-2,   192.168.0.3
```

**Question 1** Can I automatically create edges between the first and third entry?

**Question 2** If I added a fifth entry `Beta, storage-3, 192.168.0.2` , would the link be efficiently (and preferable automatically) created between the second and fifth entry?

**Question 3** What if I added a third system Gamma, where only the last byte is specified, and it is assumed that the first three are `192.168.0`, can I concatenate the two together and still automatically create edges against Alpha and Beta entries?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the OrientDB ETL tool:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/ETL-Introduction.html

It can load from CSVs:
http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Extractor.html#csv-extractor

And transform to Vertexes and Endges
http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Transformer.html

Of course, you can write some custom  code to load your specific  CSV to OrientDB.

Comment: Hi Roberto,  The vertices have already been loaded into an Orient database.  Is there a way to automatically create the edges between the servers vertices?